# How To Filter Out A Subdirectory In Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site that has multiple sub directories.  One of these directory locations is `/careers/` which in itself, has over 300 child pages.

When I go to in Google Analytics, and attempt to filter by `/career pages, this is all I see...

[image]

...I do not want to checkbox all values that contain 300+ career items. That's insane! How can I properly **filter** for any `/careers/*` items in Google Analytics for landing pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I have found to get a listing of all `/career/*` pages was to create a report in **Explore**.  If you have the time to craft a custom report in this section of Google Analytics, you may find the following steps helpful.

- Create a new blank report
- Give it an exploration name
- Give it a date range
- My Segment consisted of using 4 **Page Location** values with an **Or** statements connecting each one :

  - The first value was the URL to the landing page of /career/
  - The second value was **does it contain ?**
  - The third value was **does it contain %**
  - The fourth value was **ends with  /**
- My Dimensions is set to **Page Location**
- My Metrics consist of **Views, Total Users, First Visits, Views per user**, and **Exits**.
- My Technique is set to **Free Form**
- My Visualization is set to **Table**
- My Segment Comparison is set to the Segment mentioned above.
- My Pivot is set to **First Column**
- My Rows is set to **Page Location**
- My Values are set to all my Metrics mentioned above.
- My Cell Type is set to **Bar Chart**.

As a result you may find a solution close to the following visual example...

[image]

In addition, [here's the official guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7579450?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) on getting started with Explorations, beyond my very specific, custom situation.